# OSX 10.6.8 crash: suspected audio layer hard freeze on an iMac CWI39445

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, crash

The following is a simple question that's difficult for me to diagnose because it causes a hard freeze that the system daemons appear to not be able to log. As a power user, I'm in full control of my system as root and expect, from circumstantial evidence, that this is related to an audio driver issue with the latest update to `10.6.8`. I do not know how to fix the problem, however.

First, let's compare a standard case of improper shutdown, according to `system.log`, wherein I held down the power button to reboot the machine. Note that the hostname of my box in these logs has been replaced with `hostname` to prevent identifiability.

```
Oct 18 12:20:29 hostname com.apple.launchd.peruser.364919944[304] (com.apple.PreferenceSyncAgent): fork() failed, will try again in one second: Resource temporarily unavailable
Oct 18 12:20:29 hostname postfix/sendmail[98904]: warning: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Oct 18 12:21:31 localhost com.apple.kextd[10]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
Oct 18 12:21:20 localhost com.apple.launchd[1]: *** launchd[1] has started up. ***
```

Now, let's look at `system.log` during one of these hard freezes:

```
Oct 18 14:27:18 localhost com.apple.kextd[10]: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
Oct 18 14:27:09 localhost com.apple.launchd[1]: *** launchd[1] has started up. ***
Oct 18 14:27:19 localhost DirectoryService[11]: Improper shutdown detected
Oct 18 14:27:20 localhost blued[15]: Apple Bluetooth daemon started
```

`kernel.log`, standard improper shutdown:

```
Oct 18 12:18:14 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != result" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 765 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:14 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != result" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 795 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:14 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != dispatchToStateMachinePosition ( dequeuedEvent )" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 721 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:14 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != result" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 765 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:14 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != result" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 795 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:14 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != dispatchToStateMachinePosition ( dequeuedEvent )" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 721 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:28 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != result" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 765 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:28 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != result" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 795 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:28 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != dispatchToStateMachinePosition ( dequeuedEvent )" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 721 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:28 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != result" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 765 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:28 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != result" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 795 goto handler
Oct 18 12:18:28 hostname kernel[0]: Sound assertion "0 != dispatchToStateMachinePosition ( dequeuedEvent )" failed in AppleMikeyDevice at line 721 goto handler
Oct 18 12:21:31 localhost kernel[0]: npvhash=4095
Oct 18 12:21:31 localhost kernel[0]: PAE enabled
Oct 18 12:21:31 localhost kernel[0]: 64 bit mode enabled
```

`kernel.log`, hard freeze:

```
Oct 18 13:45:19 hostname kernel[0]: CoreServicesUIAg[1076] Unable to clear quarantine `Headers': 93
Oct 18 13:45:19 hostname kernel[0]: CoreServicesUIAg[1076] Unable to clear quarantine `Resources': 93
Oct 18 13:45:19 hostname kernel[0]: CoreServicesUIAg[1076] Unable to clear quarantine `Sparkle': 93
Oct 18 13:45:19 hostname kernel[0]: CoreServicesUIAg[1076] Unable to clear quarantine `Current': 93
Oct 18 14:27:18 localhost kernel[0]: npvhash=4095
Oct 18 14:27:18 localhost kernel[0]: PAE enabled
Oct 18 14:27:18 localhost kernel[0]: 64 bit mode enabled
```

Note that the complaints from `CoreServicesUIAg` are consistent across both hard freezes.

I have no additional information, insofar as no `.hang` or `.crash` appear to have been generated on my system and all other logs look fine. I did, however, leave this workstation locked overnight and did not suffer the same hard freeze, and I appear to be doing just fine typing out this message on the machine with audio disabled.

**Addendum**: core temperature and other hardware diagnostics appeared to be reporting within completely tolerable ranges. The last read I'd received before the second crash was somewhere in the 54-55°C range, which is pretty cool as far as CPUs are concerned.

**Second Addendum**: [this article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20075185-263/workaround-for-audio-problems-with-os-x-10.6.8-update/) may be related, but I have no testing data. If this is plausible, I'll simply roll back to `10.6.7` and see what happens.

---

*Is there any information available for this problem? If so, is there a simple hotfix or solution I can apply to my machine to regain stability without rolling back to a previous version?*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the lack of responsiveness to this question and a lack of any further crashes from this machine after disabling the audio layer, I've decided to extract the HDA kernel drivers from `10.6.7` to resolve this issue. This seems to be the right course of action.